# Running multiple instances of the same script NodeJS - Child Processes

Tags: node.js, linux, process, child-process

I have a script which queries an API, the input to the script is a unique user ID which will determine what endpoint is queried on the API.

I want to spawn multiple instances of this script for the given X number of users and wondering what is the best solution for this?

I have looked into NodeJS [child processes](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html), is this the main way of solving this problem within node, spawning multiple child processes from a main process? Are all these processes then running on one thread I assume as NodeJS is single threaded?

The script that I want to spawn multiple process's of will be running constantly once it is started, querying an API for data every second. I guess it will have to factor in how much compute power I have available but generally how scalable is the [child processes](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) way of doing things?

Also in the background would a NodeJS child process be doing the same thing as if I was to run a bash command `index.js &` and spawn different processes? (Aside from being able to control the child processes then from the main process in NodeJS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you require can be done using a process manager like pm2.

You can read up more about pm2 [here](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2).

To launch multiple instances as a cluster using pm2 with the following syntax.

```
pm2 start server.js -i 4
```

The above command would launch 4 instances of server.js. Also note that you do a lot of configuration using a config file (read docs for it) and it even supports multi-threading.

Comment: Hi sorry for the late, reply going to have a look into this now thanks for the suggestion! Still open to other solutions too if anyone has any.

Comment: Yep I have marked as answer this is the way to go, thanks for help!

Comment: You may be able to help with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64910872/pm2-catching-errored-state-signal

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this cli tool](https://github.com/realrecordzLab/process-cycler) to achive the thing you need. The library will ask for a script to spawn and will cycle it's execution with multiple child process.