# PM2 Catching Errored State Signal

Tags: node.js, linux, process, pm2

I am trying to catch the process before it goes into the state of errored. The process I am running is erroring and restarting correctly. After 15 attempts of restarting it will go into a state of errored, as shown for the process with an ID of `0` below.

```
┌─────┬─────────────────────────────────────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id  │ name                                    │ namespace   │ version │ mode    │ pid      │ uptime │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ mem      │ user     │ watching │
├─────┼─────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 1   │ a58a1e0d-3a6f-4512-8b83-4dcfd2f9e408    │ default     │ 1.0.0   │ fork    │ 3139     │ 8s     │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 61.6mb   │ warren   │ disabled │
│ 0   │ e95ff617-4800-4059-906b-2cde63bcb4b6    │ default     │ 1.0.0   │ fork    │ 0        │ 0      │ 15   │ errored   │ 0%       │ 0b       │ warren   │ disabled │
└─────┴─────────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

Before it goes into a state of errored what signal (if any) is sent to the process?

For example when I issue a `pm2 stop <PROCESS_NAME>` I can can intercept the `SIGINT` message and log something to my log file as in the example below.

```
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
  logger.info("I HAVE BEEN KILLED")
})
```

I need something like this but the signal sent to the process when it switches to an errored state is listened for.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the local library of [pm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2) to catch the state of errored processes from logs.

1. npm install pm2 on your project directory
2. Go into the file where process is initiated
3. Add the following command into the file, it will add an event listener your process and will catch if error occured

   ```
   const pm2 = require('pm2')    
   pm2.launchBus(function(err, bus) {
       bus.on('log:err', function(e) {
           //When a task throws errors
       });
   });
   ```